# Or condition in Shell script in Solaris

Tags: bash, shell, solaris

When I run this code in Solaris bash:

```
a=false;
b=false;

if [ $a -o $b ] ; then
    echo "_True"
else
    echo "_False"
fi
```

result:

> _True

**Shouldn't the output of the script be false?**

If I modify the script to something like this:

```
a=false;
b=false;

if [ $a = true -o $b = true ] ; then
    echo "_True"
else
    echo "_False"
fi
```

result:

> _False

but this doesn't feel like a good coding practice to write "$a = true".

Please, can i know what is the issue here? and what exactly is the solution?

Comment: `false` is not a magic string in shell scripts. `[` only tests that the string is not empty. (If it was empty in this case the `[` would fail because you're not quoting your variables. Tip: https://www.shellcheck.net/)

Comment: Or if `$a` and `$b` are actually the names of commands you want to execute, perhaps you are looking for `if $a || $b; then`...

Comment: no @tripleee, The variable should treat as a boolean. So, it's value will be true-false or 1-0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `[` command treats all non-empty strings as true. So use an empty string to represent false, rather than the string `"false"`. And remember to quote the variables.

```
a=
b=

if [ "$a" -o "$b" ]; then
    echo "_True"
else
    echo "_False"
fi
```

Another option is to use the `true` and `false` commands, rather than `[`.

```
a=false
b=false
if $a || $b; then
    echo "_True"
else
    echo "_False"
fi
```

Comment: and what should be the value when i want to specify the variable to be true.?

Comment: Do you think assigning false to variable is totally wrong here.? If yes, is there any other way other than assigning blank value.?

Comment: You can do it if you want to use your second format where you test `$a = true`. It's entirely up to your personal style.